# How to add an event to a quicklaunch item in SharePoint?

Tags: events

I want to add an event to one of my quicklaunch items in SharePoint, but I don't know how to do that.

Or maybe to link the item to a page that would do what I want and then close and then come back to the previous one.

Do you have any idea how I can do this ?

Comment: Via code or UI?

Comment: What exactly will the event do? I mean what kind of functionality do you want to add to the Quick launch menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a visual guide that may help you: http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-add-a-link-to-the-quick-launch-toolbar-in-sharepoint-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score -1):

Here is a method to add an item to the quick launch in C#

```
private void AddNodeToQuickLaunch(string linkName, string SiteToOpen, string pathtoPage)
   {
       try
       {
           using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb(SiteToOpen))
           {
               web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

               SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;

               SPNavigationNode createNode = new SPNavigationNode(linkName, pathtoPage, true);

               foreach (SPNavigationNode node in nodes)
               {
                   bool nodeExists = false;
                   if (node.Title.Equals("Lists"))
                   {
                       foreach (SPNavigationNode child in node.Children)
                       {
                           if (child.Title == linkName)
                           {
                               nodeExists = true;
                           }
                       }

                       if (!nodeExists)
                       {
                           node.Children.Add(createNode, node);
                       }
                   }
               }
               web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
   }
```

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. Also we  require disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.